# Formulas to determine the value of graph energy with addition or deletion of edges

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrices

If $G$ is a graph, then the graph energy of $G$ denoted  by $E(G)$ is defined as the sum of absolute values of eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of $G$. It is known that $E(G)\geq E(G-v)$,  where $ v$ is a vertex in $G$. But it is not known that how the energy of a graph and its subgraphs are related if the number of vertices are same in both the graphs.

I am trying to formulate increasing or decreasing pattern of energy of a graph and its subsequent subgraphs on the same set of vertices. For instance, I am taking a complete graph $G=K_4$ with four vertices. Then I have the following observations.

(1)  $E(G)=6$

(2) $E(G_1)=5.1231056256=1+\sqrt{17}$, where $G_1$ is a subgraph obtained by deleting one edge from $G$.

Similarly,

(3) $E(G_2)=4=2\sqrt{4}$ (obtained by deleting two edges from $G$)

(4) $E(G_3)=4.472135955=2\sqrt{5}$ (obtained by deleting three edges from $G$)

(5) $E(G_4)=2\sqrt{2}$ (obtained by deleting four edges from $G$)

(6) $G_5=2=2\sqrt{1}$ (obtained by deleting five edges from $G$).

I would really appreciate if someone could help me arriving at a generalizing  formula of the above pattern in particular. That is, what is the general pattern in which the energy is increasing or decreasing in the above example?

Comment: People interested in this question may also be interested by your post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4002762/graphs-with-maximum-and-minimum-graph-energies

Comment: I do not understand your second sentence: it claims that the energy decreases when we remove an edge (which seems wrong from your $K_4$ example) but then the sentence talks about vertices. Did I miss something?

Comment: @MatthieuLatapy I have mentioned that the energy increases or drecreases. Well, the set of vertices remains same in all the graphs.

Comment: @gete you have an error in the question, you say that $E(G) \geqslant E(G-e)$ where $e$ is an edge, which is not true.

Comment: @GordonRoyle Thank you for pointing the error. It is corrected now.